# Issue with logger and array expansion in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I have a script that uses an array to add http post data to a curl request, e.g. `params+=(-d paramname=paramvalue)`

If I test the output with `echo`, I see it expand the array properly. When I pass it to `logger`, however, it loses the `-d` after the first one. What am I doing wrong?

```
#!/bin/bash
params=(-d pa=asdf)
params+=(-d p1=p1)
echo "${params[@]}"
logger -t "test"  -p user.info -i "why doesn't this work ${params[@]}"
```

Output: `-d pa=asdf -d p1=p1`

But `tail /var/log/syslog` gives me `Jan 15 20:00:51 fserver test[17781]: why doesn't this work -d pa=asdf p1=p1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"${params[@]}"` expands to the contents of the array *with each element treated as a separate word (argument)*. Thus, `echo "${params[@]}"` is equivalent to `echo "-d" "pa=asdf" "-d" "p1=p1".`echo` sticks its arguments together with spaces in between, so this looks fine. But when you run

```
logger -t "test"  -p user.info -i "why doesn't this work ${params[@]}"
```

it's equivalent to

```
logger -t "test"  -p user.info -i "why doesn't this work -d" "pa=asdf" "-d" "p1=p1"
```

So only the first `-d` is passed as part of the message string. The `pa=asdf` argument gets appended to the message (as `echo` did). The second `-d` gets passed as its own argument, which (I suspect) `logger` interprets as a command option, rather than part of the message string. Then `p1=p1` gets treated as part of the message.

Solution: use `[*]` instead of `[@]`:

```
logger -t "test"  -p user.info -i "why doesn't this work ${params[*]}"
```

The `[*]` tells the shell to paste all of the array elements together with spaces (or whatever's the first character of `IFS`) between them, rather than splitting them into separate words. Usually, `[@]` is what you want; this is one of the few exceptions.

Comment: Thank you! What do you mean by "IFS"

Comment: `IFS` is a special shell variable that defines how the shell splits and merges "words". Basically, it's a list of characters that the shell treats as whitespace. The default is space+tab+newline. See [here](https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/$IFS) for more info.